# How to speedup IronPython startup?

Tags: c#, ironpython

I use Ironpython 2.7.7 in my C# application. When i run a python script for the first time, it take around 40 seconds for ironpython.dll to run the script. After that the script can run much faster(less that 1s)

Why is that? Can i do anything to speed it up?

Comment: That's quite excessive.  There isn't much that takes half a trillion cpu cycles, delays that long are caused by either network timeouts or anti-malware being anti.

Comment: @samad that might be more .net or IronPython related depending on what your script is doing. Are there many python libs involved or does your script spend most of its time calling to .net? Do you interact with lots of files/IO that might be cached/warmed up after the initial run?